# Silverlight automatically choose security transport mode between http and https

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ssl, silverlight-4.0

Our Silverlight Application can run in both *http* and *https* (SSL, using *Transport* Security) Mode. In our `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` file we simply configured our Service Endpoint this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultEndpoint"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
          <!-- Enable for SSL: mode="Transport" -->
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="/services/DefaultService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="DefaultEndpoint"
                contract="OurNamespace.IOurContractAsync"
                name="DefaultEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The configured Endpoint can be accessed in both Modes. It simply depends in which context the XAP file was loaded: From `http://example.com/slpage.html` or `https://example.com/slpage.html`. Unfortunately, we have to manually switch the **Security Mode** setting between "None" and "Transport". Everything else would already work as desired. When Security Mode is "None" and we access via https, we get an Exception that "..https was provided but http was expected..." and vice versa. Any chance to let Silverlight automatically decide which Security Mode should be used? What is the simplest solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we finally ended up with the following solution (not exactly what Valentin suggested, but +1 for help!):

The `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` contains both binding and endpoint configurations like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
          <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="/services/DefaultService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"
                contract="OurNamespace.IOurContractAsync"
                name="DefaultEndpoint" />
      <endpoint address="/services/DefaultService.svc"
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
                contract="OurNamespace.IOurContractAsync"
                name="SecureEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

On initialization, we read the `App.Current.Host.Source.Scheme` Property. The Service client is generated by the `ChannelFactory`, the code is similar to this snippet:

```
protected string EndpointName {
  get {
    return (App.Current.Host.Source.Scheme == "https") ?
      "SecureEndpoint" : "DefaultEndpoint";
  }
}

protected IOurContractAsync CreateInterface() {
  var channelFactory = ChannelFactory<IOurContractAsync>(EndpointName);
  return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: yeah looks better than passing https=true param if you can read it from Scheme with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be a number of ways one is to provide initparams to SL app from your web pages like

> param name="initParams"
>   value="Https=true"

for https page
 and false for html page. parse it
 inside SL and set up security mode for
 endpoint.

You can create/edit endpoint proxy programmatically in your SL app.

Another way could be setting transport behaviour based on link inside SL app without initparams (if begins with https ->transport else none) I believe once sl app is downloaded link should be not relative and this should be a working solution.

You can make a factory method to create service proxy and put this setup proxy logic inside it , which would be simpler than completely removing this serviceconfig file.

You would simply call

```
MyServiceClient client = Factory.MakeClient()
```

and I think its an elegant enough solution. in MakeClient you decide what transport security to use and its done.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yeah I'm already aware of some programmatic solutions for most i can throw away the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` completely, which I didn't like to do...